# Kotlin Secondary Constructor and Primary Constructor

Tags: class, kotlin, constructor

```
class EditorImpl(text: String) : Editor {
    private val myDocument: Document

    init {
        myDocument = DocumentImpl(text)
    }

    //secondary constructor
    constructor(document: Document) : this(document.getText()) {

    }

    override fun getText(): CharSequence {
        return myDocument.getText()
    }

    override fun setText(text: String) {
        myDocument.setText(text)
    }

    override fun getChars(): CharSequence {
        return getText()
    }

    override fun putChar(chars: CharSequence) {
        setText(chars.toString())
    }

    override fun getDocument(): Document {
        return myDocument
    }
}
```

How do I make sure that '**document**' parameter passed in the secondary constructor is assigned to '**myDocument**' field as every secondary constructor is required to call the primary constructor? I don't want to swap the constructors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I don't want to swap the constructors* - why?

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned you don't want to swap the constructors, but if you have no real reason against it, it should definitely be the way to go.

If it makes sense that users can create an instance with a custom document, then this should be the primary constructor because it is the one that defines the most things for the class. The constructor with `text` is just sugar to automatically create a `Document` from this text:

```kotlin
class EditorImpl(private val myDocument: Document) : Editor {

    constructor(text: String) : this(DocumentImpl(text))

    override fun getText(): CharSequence = myDocument.getText()

    override fun setText(text: String) {
        myDocument.setText(text)
    }

    override fun getChars(): CharSequence = getText()

    override fun putChar(chars: CharSequence) {
        setText(chars.toString())
    }

    override fun getDocument(): Document = myDocument
}
```

Also as a side note, are `Document` and `Editor` defined in Java? This setter/getter approach is not very idiomatic in Kotlin, if these are custom classes/interfaces, consider using Kotlin properties instead.